# Limitation of Attachment size when using SMTP

Tags: visual-c++, smtp

I wrote a C++ program to send a mail using SMTP. But when I attach any files I notices that a **single file's size always is limited to 808 bytes**. As an example if I send a text file with 10 KBs, when I download the attachment it has only text worth 808 bytes. If the large file is a zip file, it gets corrupted in unzipping obviously due to CRC failure. I used a  MAPI library to send larger files without a problem. Is this a network limitation of SMTP? Can someone please explain why this is happening??

Thank You!!!

Comment: SMTP has no such limitation.  It must be your implementation. If you show some code, and perhaps stick around to answer some questions, maybe we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

How are you attaching and encoding the files? Are you using MIME? 8-bit clean?

SMTP has no built in limits, but has specific limits in how data is transferred (formatting, etc). In general, most mail systems reject mails with greater than 5-10MB of data.

Comment: I agree, I would look at how your SMTP server is set up.  There is fairly simple command line Telnet tools debug a SMTP server.  This might prove useful if you don't have access to the SMTP server :)